# Why is the combiner of the Collector interface not consistent with the overloaded collect method?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

There is an overload method, `collect()`, in interface `Stream<T>` with the following signature:

```
<R> R collect(Supplier<R> supplier,
          BiConsumer<R,? super T> accumulator,
          BiConsumer<R,R> combiner)
```

There is another version of `collect(Collector<? super T,A,R> collector)`, which receives an object with the previous three functions. The property of the interface `Collector` corresponding to the `combiner` has the signature `BinaryOperator<A> combiner()`.

In the latter case, the Java API 8 states that:

> The combiner function may fold state from one argument into the other and return that, or may return a new result container.

Why does the former `collect` method not receive a `BinaryOperator<R>` too?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The "inline" (3-arg) version of `collect` is designed for when you already have these functions "lying around".  For example:

```
ArrayList<Foo> list = stream.collect(ArrayList::new, 
                                     ArrayList::add,
                                     ArrayList::addAll);
```

Or

```
BitSet bitset = stream.collect(BitSet::new, 
                               BitSet::set,
                               BitSet::or);
```

While these are just motivating examples, our explorations with similar existing builder classes was that the signatures of the existing combiner candidates were more suited to conversion to BiConsumer than to BinaryOperator.  Offering the "flexibility" you ask for would make this overload far less useful in the very cases it was designed to support -- which is when you've already got the functions lying around, and you don't want to have to make (or learn about making) a Collector just to collect them.

Collector, on the other hand, has a far wider range of uses, and so merits the additional flexibility.

Comment: another question on collect - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30310749/why-dont-primitive-stream-have-collectcollector

Comment: `StringBuilder::append` is a bad example as it *does* return the container. But [`BitSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) would be a good candidate.

Comment: It looks like the documentation of the inline version of `combiner` is missing a critical detail: which side should receive the result of the merge? The BinaryOperator version can leave that up to the implementer, but the BiConsumer needs to specify which is primary.

Answer (score 5):

Keep in mind that the primary purpose of `Stream.collect()` is to support [*Mutable Reduction*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction). For this operation, both functions, the *accumulator* and the *combiner* are meant to manipulate the mutable container and don’t need to return a value.

Therefore it is much more convenient not to insist on returning a value. As [Brian Goetz has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30309439/2711488), this decision allows to re-use a lot of existing container types and their methods. Without the ability to use these types directly, the entire three-arg `collect` method would be pointless.

In contrast, the `Collector` interface is an *abstraction* of this operation supporting much more use cases. Most notably, you can even model the ordinary, i.e. non-mutable, [*Reduction*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Reduction) operation with value types (or types having value type semantics) [via a `Collector`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#reducing-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-). In this case, there *must* be a return value as the value objects themselves must not be modified.

Of course, it is not meant to be used as `stream.collect(Collectors.reducing(…))` instead of `stream.reduce(…)`. Instead, this abstraction comes handy when *combining* collectors, e.g. like `groupingBy(…,reducing(…))`.

Answer (score 2):

If the former `collect` method receive a `BinaryOperator<R>` then the following example would not compile:

```
ArrayList<Foo> list = stream.collect(ArrayList::new, 
                                     ArrayList::add,
                                     ArrayList::addAll);
```

In this case the compiler could not infer the return type of the `combiner` and would give a compilation error.

So if this version of `collect` method was consistent with the `Collector` interface then it would promote a more complex use of this version of `collect` method, that was not intended.