# How to map two arrays to one HashMap in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, hashmap

I have two String arrays. One having short name.

```
// days short name
String[] shortNames = {"SUN", "MON", "...", "SAT"};
```

The other having long name.

```
// days long name
String[] longNames = {"SUNDAY", "MONDAY", "....", "SATURDAY"};
```

Both having same number of elements. How can I map short name as KEY and long name as VALUE in HashMap?

```
HashMap<String, String> days = new HashMap<>();
```

I know, I can make by looping. Is there a better way?

Comment: I think looping is the best way in this context - when the size of these two arrays are same.

Comment: Why store in array in the first place?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There are lots of ways you can do this. One that is fairly easy to understand and apply is using Java 8 streams and collectors to map from a stream of indices to key value pairs:

```
Map<String, String> days = IntStream.range(0, shortNames.length).boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> shortNames[i], i -> longNames[i]));
```

There are some third party Java libraries that include a 'zip' function to take two streams and produce a map from one to the other. But really they are just neater ways of achieving the same thing as the code above.

Comment: and what about java 7 and below?

Comment: @10sw33 Below Java 8 (other than upgrading!) you still have a few options. Use a third party library or use `Arrays.toList(shortNames).forEach` to go through all the items in one array and add the map entries. I know this is really just iteration by another name but then so also are streams!

Comment: @sprinter Good answer, but he needs boxed() as Jens said below.

Answer (score 3):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30339737/1725096) did not work for me, as the `IntStream` does not provide a one-argument `collect` method.

To nevertheless benefit from the `toMap` collector you have to box the `int` primitives into `Integer` objects first. If you like to preserve the element order, use the extended version of `toMap` together with `LinkedHashMap::new` like shown below:

```
package learning.java8;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import org.junit.Test;

public class IntStreamLT {

    @Test
    public void q30339679() {

        final String[] shortNames = getDayOfWeekNamesInEnglish(TextStyle.SHORT);
        final String[] longNames = getDayOfWeekNamesInEnglish(TextStyle.FULL);

        final Map<String, String> days = IntStream.range(0, shortNames.length).boxed()
                .collect(toMap(i -> shortNames[i], i -> longNames[i]));

        System.out.println(days);

        final Map<String, String> sorted = IntStream.range(0, shortNames.length).boxed()
                .collect(toMap(
                        i -> shortNames[i], i -> longNames[i],
                        (i, j) -> i, LinkedHashMap::new));

        System.out.println(sorted);

        assertEquals("{Mon=Monday, Tue=Tuesday, Wed=Wednesday, Thu=Thursday, "
                + "Fri=Friday, Sat=Saturday, Sun=Sunday}", sorted.toString());
    }

    private static String[] getDayOfWeekNamesInEnglish(final TextStyle style) {

        return Arrays.stream(DayOfWeek.values())
                .map(day -> day.getDisplayName(style, Locale.ENGLISH))
                .toArray(String[]::new);
    }
}
```

see also: [Why don't primitive Stream have collect(Collector)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30310749/1725096)

Comment: How do I do this while also sorting the hashmap in descending/ascending order?

Comment: @ColstonBod-oy You could add e.g. `.sorted(Comparator.comparing(i -> shortNames[i]))` before `.collect(...)`. If this does not help, it might be better to ask a new question.

Comment: yup! it does work, how can I do descending order as well?

Comment: @ColstonBod-oy `.sorted(Comparator.comparing(i -> shortNames[i], Comparator.reverseOrder()))`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils`.

Here is an example:

```
Map colorMap = ArrayUtils.toMap(new String[][] {
    {"RED", "#FF0000"},
    {"GREEN", "#00FF00"},
    {"BLUE", "#0000FF"}});
```