# Converting Arrays to List

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I've got small question about converting an array to a list. Let's say I've got an array of Strings. If I'd like to have it as a list I code sth like this:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(stringArray));
```

But If I got the same situation but my array was an array of ints I'd had to do converting this way:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(intArray).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Why? What's the meaning of .boxed() and .collect(Collectors.toList())?

Comment: "_What's the meaning of .boxed() and .collect(Collectors.toList())?_" Did you read the documentation for those methods? Which part of that documentation was not clear?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't Collectors.toList() work on primitive collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38964268/why-doesnt-collectors-tolist-work-on-primitive-collections)

Comment: Note that `.collect(Collectors.toList())` does not necessarily return an `ArrayList`; it could be some other kind of list. I presume you specifically want an ArrayList because you create one in your first code snippet.

Answer (score 3):

https://howtodoinjava.com/java8/java8-boxed-intstream/

> To convert a stream of primitives, you must first box the elements in their wrapper class and then collect them. This type of stream in called boxed stream.

So, `int` is a primitive version of `Integer` (i.e. its not an object reference).  So, you have to convert the primitive data type to the Integer object reference.

The primitive is not an acceptable parameter to `Arrays.asList()`.

As for collect() - That is just the standard method to convert a stream of elements back into a result collection.  You could make it int a list, a set, a map (if you had a value you'd like to put next to it), or whatever.

Answer (score 3):

*First of all why you need the second way is because you can't have List of primitive data type ,as the String is an object in java thats why you were able to convert array of string to list of string using 1st technique, but since int is primit*ive data type thats'y you need to convert it to Integer first then create a list.

***Let me split this whole line in three part***

```
List<Integer> list=Arrays.stream(intArray).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

1.`Arrays.stream(intArray)`:

> This will take input as an arrays (here intArray) and return a stream
>   of elements present in array.

2.`.boxed()` :

> Boxing and unboxing in java is conversion of primitive data type to
>   Wrapper(reference data type) and vice-versa. now this methos `boxed()`
>   works on stream of input data and return an stream of Integer after
>   boxing each element in the stream to Integer.

3.`collect(Collectors.toList()):`

> now that you have got stream of Integer from `boxed()`  you need to
>   store it to some collection. `collect()` works on stream of data and 
>   the paramter passed to it tells the type collections to which  data of
>   the stream should  be mapped to. in your case it is list so
>   `Collector.toList()` is used. .

Answer (score 1):

It's when a primitive `int` when converted to it's *boxed* equivalent `Integer` class. All Java primitives have a boxed equivalent class (boolean -> Boolean, long -> Long, etc).

So in your example you are converting a `Stream` of primitive `int` into a `Stream<Integer>` when you call `.boxed()`

Comment: There's no such thing as `Stream<int>` - presumably you mean `IntStream`.

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.stream(intArray)` returns an `IntStream` -  a sequence of primitive int-valued elements. Now if we check [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) for `IntStream` we can see that there isn't method `collect` which accepts an instance of `Collector`. On the contrary there is the following [method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.ObjIntConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-):

```
IntStream#collect(Supplier,ObjIntConsumer,BiConsumer)
```

> Performs a mutable reduction operation on the elements of this stream.

You still can transform your `IntStream` into a `List` without using `boxed`.

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(intArray)
             .collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add, ArrayList::addAll);
```

It works in the following way:

- `ArrayList::new` is a Supplier - a function that creates a new result container, in our case a new ArrayList.
- `ArrayList::add` is a ObjIntConsumer - a function which adds an additional element into a result container.
- `ArrayList::addAll` is a BiConsumer - a function for combining two values. It is used when stream is executed in parallel to combine two partial results. In this case if stream produces 2 `ArrayList` we need to combine them into one and proceed to the next stage.

All these 3 elements could be abstracted into one single call using `collect(Collectors.toList())`. But in order to use a `Collector` an primitive stream `IntStream` must be converted to more general `Stream<Integer>`. This could be done using `boxed()` method which just performs this conversion.

I hope this helps.