# Where is defined the combination order of the combiner of collect(supplier, accumulator, combiner)?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

The Java API documentations states that the `combiner` parameter of the `collect` method must be:

> an associative, non-interfering, stateless function for combining two values, which must be compatible with the accumulator function

A `combiner` is a `BiConsumer<R,R>` that receives two parameters of type `R` and returns `void`. But the documentation does not state if we should combine the elements into the first or the second parameter?

For instance the following examples may give different results, depending on the order of combination be:  `m1.addAll(m2)` or `m2.addAll(m1)`.

```
List<String> res = LongStream
     .rangeClosed(1, 1_000_000)
     .parallel()
     .mapToObj(n -> "" + n)
     .collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add,(m1, m2) -> m1.addAll(m2));
```

I know that in this case we could simply use a method handle, such as `ArrayList::addAll`. Yet, there are some cases where it is required a Lambda and we must combine the items in the correct order, otherwise we could get an inconsistent result when processing in parallel.

Is this claimed in any part of the Java 8 API documentation? Or it really doesn't matter?

Comment: You are right, the javadoc isn't very clearly written -- confusingly, it says that combiner must be associative!.  It is probably a left-over from an earlier version, which used a `BinaryOperator` rather than a `BiConsumer`.  But from the given examples it is plainly clear that combiner must accumulate into its first argument.

Comment: 1. [Original version that uses `BinaryOperator` in a `reduceBy` method](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/lambda/lambda/jdk/diff/ae4e5994cbb4/src/share/classes/java/util/streams/Stream.java#l1.9). 2. [The version that removes `reduceBy` method and replaces it with `mutableReduce` methods, one of which uses `BiBlock` which is equivalent to  `BiConsumer`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/lambda/lambda/jdk/rev/5d25f6772fec?revcount=240#l4.35). 3. [This version of the documentation](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/lambda/lambda/jdk/diff/fe7cc4f69664/src/share/classes/java/util/stream/Stream.java#l1.224).

Comment: [4. The associativity constraint of the combiner is explained in one of the answers below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30530572/571168).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems that this is not explicitly stated in the documentation. However there's an [ordering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Ordering) concept in streams API. Stream can be either ordered or not. It may be unordered from the very beginning if source spliterator is unordered (for example, if the stream source is `HashSet`). Or the stream may become unordered if user explicitly used `unordered()` operation. If the stream is ordered, then collection procedure should also be stable, thus, I guess, it's *assumed* that for ordered streams the `combiner` receives the arguments in the strict order. However it's not guaranteed for an unordered stream.

Answer (score 11):

Of course, it matters, as when you use `m2.addAll(m1)` instead of `m1.addAll(m2)`, it doesn’t just change the order of elements, but completely breaks the operation. Since a `BiConsumer` doesn’t return a result, you have no control over which object the caller will use as the result and since the caller will use the first one, modifying the second instead will cause data loss.

There is a hint if you look at the *accumulator* function which has the type `BiConsumer<R,? super T>`, in other words can’t do anything else than storing the element of type `T`, provided as second argument, into the container of type `R`, provided as first argument.

If you look at the [documentation of `Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html), which uses a `BinaryOperator` as *combiner* function, hence allows the *combiner* to decide which argument to return (or even an entirely different result instance), you find:

> The associativity constraint says that splitting the computation must produce an equivalent result. That is, for any input elements `t1` and `t2`, the results `r1` and `r2` in the computation below must be equivalent:
>
> ```
> A a1 = supplier.get();
> accumulator.accept(a1, t1);
> accumulator.accept(a1, t2);
> R r1 = finisher.apply(a1);  // result without splitting
>
> A a2 = supplier.get();
> accumulator.accept(a2, t1);
> A a3 = supplier.get();
> accumulator.accept(a3, t2);
> R r2 = finisher.apply(combiner.apply(a2, a3));  // result with splitting
> ```

So if we assume that the *accumulator* is applied in encounter order, the *combiner* has to combine the first and second argument in left-to-right order to produce an equivalent result.

---

Now, the three-arg version of `Stream.collect` has a slightly different signature, using a `BiConsumer` as *combiner* [exactly for supporting method references like `ArrayList::addAll`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30309439/2711488). Assuming consistency throughout all these operations and considering the purpose of this signature change, we can safely assume that it has to be the first argument which is the container to modify.

But it seems that this is a late change and the documentation hasn’t adapted accordingly. If you look at the [Mutable reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction) section of the package documentation, you will find that it has been adapted to show the actual `Stream.collect`’s signature and usage examples, but repeats exactly the same definition regarding the associativity constraint as shown above, despite the fact that `finisher.apply(combiner.apply(a2, a3))` doesn’t work if `combiner` is a `BiConsumer`…

---

The documentation issue has been reported as [JDK-8164691](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8164691) and addressed in Java 9. [The new documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) says:

> combiner - an associative, non-interfering, stateless function that accepts two partial result containers and merges them, which must be compatible with the accumulator function. The combiner function must fold the elements from the second result container into the first result container.