# Collectors.toSet implementation detail

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, java-9

I was looking at `Collectors.toSet` implementation under jdk-8 and pretty much saw the obvious thing:

```
 public static <T> Collector<T, ?, Set<T>> toSet() {
    return new CollectorImpl<>(
       (Supplier<Set<T>>) HashSet::new, 
       Set::add,
       (left, right) -> { left.addAll(right); return left; }, // combiner
       CH_UNORDERED_ID);
```

Look at the `combiner` for a moment; this has been discussed before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30526324/where-is-defined-the-combination-order-of-the-combiner-of-collectsupplier-accu), but the idea is that `a combiner folds from the second argument into the first`. And that obviously happens here.

But then I looked into `jdk-9` implementation and saw this:

```
 public static <T> Collector<T, ?, Set<T>> toSet() {
    return new CollectorImpl<>(
       (Supplier<Set<T>>) HashSet::new, 
       Set::add,
       (left, right) -> {
          if (left.size() < right.size()) {
            right.addAll(left); return right;
          } else {
             left.addAll(right); return left;
          }
       },
       CH_UNORDERED_ID);
```

Now *why* this happens is a bit obvious - it takes less time to add `less elements to a bigger Set, then the other way around`. But is that really cheaper than plain `addAll`, consider the extra overhead for the branch too?

Also this breaks my *law* about always folding left...

Can someone shed some light here?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You already understand the performance rationale for the `jdk-9` implementation. Why would you expect this law of yours to be upheld if it results in much less efficient programs?

Comment: I'm not sure that your law is reflected in that answer. Nothing is specified about folding *left* consistently, especially in the accepted answer which gives the ordered vs. unordered stream distinction.

Comment: @gyre you might be right.. Seems like a bit rushed question.

Comment: The question you linked is about `Stream.collect` method, and here you are talking about a `Collector` implementation.

Comment: See http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2016-August/042800.html for some performance numbers. And also https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8164189 for the associated JBS bug.

Comment: @StefanZobel thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The combiner function of a `Collector` will *receive* the `left` and `right` appropriately, if there is an encounter order to maintain, however, it is up to the `Collector`, how it will actually combine these two arguments.

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html#combiner--) states:

> A function that accepts two partial results and merges them. The combiner function may fold state from one argument into the other and return that, or may return a new result container.

For collecting into a `List`, it would be disastrous if we just swap `left.addAll(right)` to `right.addAll(left)`, but for an unordered `Set`, it doesn’t matter. The `toSet()` collector even reports the [`UNORDERED`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.Characteristics.html#UNORDERED) characteristic to hint to the `Stream` (or any client code) that it won’t even matter which argument is provided as `left` or `right`, so a parallel stream could combine arbitrary partial results, whatever has finished first, in other words, it may behave like an unordered stream, even if the source had an encounter order (Java 8’s implementation doesn’t use that opportunity).

Regarding whether it is worth it… We are comparing a single additional branch with potentially thousands of `add` operations we can save, *each of them* bearing *multiple* conditional branches internally…