# Out of the java.util.stream.Stream interfaces's two collect methods, is one of them poorly constructed?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

In java.util.stream.Stream interface,

```
<R> R collect(Supplier<R> supplier,
              BiConsumer<R, ? super T> accumulator,
              BiConsumer<R, R> combiner);
```

the combiner is a `BiConsumer<R, R>`, whereas in

```
<R, A> R collect(Collector<? super T, A, R> collector);
```

the combiner is a `BinaryOperator<A>` which is nothing but a `BiFunction<A,A,A>`.

While the later form clearly defines what will be reference of the combined object after combining, the former form doesn't.

So how does any Stream implementation library know, what is the combined object in the former case?

Comment: @holi-java can you be little bit more specific?

Comment: A bit confused, It is not the combined, it is the accumulatar you are talking isn't it?

Comment: sorry, there is a typos, it is mutable reduction. for example: merge 2 lists into a big list to support parallel stream, which means combiner occurs in parallel streams.

Comment: @pvpkiran No, I am talking about the combiner only.

Comment: Define 'poorly constructed'. Do you mean poorly *documented*?

Comment: See also [Where is defined the combination order of the combiner of collect(supplier, accumulator, combiner)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30526324/2711488)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Java 9, the documentation of the [`Stream.collect(Supplier, BiConsumer, BiConsumer)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) method has been updated and now it explicitly mentions that you should fold elements from the second result container into the first one:

> `combiner` - an associative, non-interfering, stateless function that accepts two partial result containers and merges them, which must be compatible with the accumulator function. **The combiner function must fold the elements from the second result container into the first result container**.

(Emphasis mine).

Comment: this stands for all collectors actually, that's why I declare them usually `left, right` and always return `left`... +1

Comment: Hi @Eugene. Yes, there's no right fold in Java, it was never the intention of the designers of the stream library

Comment: @Eugene the combiner *function* is free to fold into either argument (or may even return a new object). That’s what happens with Java 9’s `toSet()`, which folds the smaller argument into the bigger one…

Comment: @Holger I guess it is free only if this is allowed, and I think `toSet` or `toMap` for example would qualify as such

Answer (score 4):

The `collect` method is supposed to be used like this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> collected = Stream.of(1,2,3)
    .collect(
        ArrayList::new, 
        ArrayList::add, 
        ArrayList::addAll);
System.out.println(collected);
```

The first argument is a supplier that supplies an empty array list for adding collected stuff into. The second argument is a biconsumer that consumes each element of the array. The third argument is there only to provide parallelism support. This enables it to collect the elements into multiple array lists at the same time, and it asks you for a way to connect all these array lists together at the end.

Why does `collect` know the result of the combination if you don't return the array list with the added item? Well, this is because `ArrayList`s are mutable. Somewhere in the implementation, it calls `accumulator.accept`:

```
// not real code, for demonstration purposes only
accumulator.accept(someArrayList, theNextElement);
```

`someArrayList` will retain all the changes made to it after `accept` returns!

Let's put this into a more familiar scenario,

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
doSomething(list);
System.out.println(list); // [1, 2, 3, 4]

private static void doSomething(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    list.add(4);
}
```

Even though `doSomething` does not return a new array list, `list` is still mutated. The same thing happens with `BiConsumer.accept`. This causes `collect` to "know" what you did to the array list.

Comment: In your example, the `BiConsumer<ArrayList<Integer>, ArrayList<Integer>> consumer = ArrayList::addAll`, which is indirectly `(a, b) -> a.addAll(b)`. And we have to **assume**  a will be used as combined object? . So here `a` is mutated, but what if i do `(a, b) -> b.addAll(a)`, so here `b` is mutated. But the later does't give right output

Comment: @boobalangnanasekaran Exactly, in the third parameter, you are _supposed_ to mutate the first argument of the BiConsumer, the second will be discarded.

Comment: But there is no such documentation or restriction,  mentioned  whatsoever.

Comment: @boobalangnanasekaran Though it is not 100% clear, the examples in the documentation of `collect` imply that you should do it this way. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. But shouldn't using a `<R> R collect(Supplier<R> supplier,
              BiConsumer<R, ? super T> accumulator,
              BinaryOperator<R> combiner);`, instead of `<R> R collect(Supplier<R> supplier,
              BiConsumer<R, ? super T> accumulator,
              BiConsumer<R, R> combiner);` is more accurate. I asked this question to know if there is some reason its defined this way that I am overlooking

Comment: @boobalangnanasekaran Well, using a `BinaryOperator` could indeed work. However, it wouldn't work so well with method references. You can't use `ArrayList::addAll` as the combiner because `addAll` is not a binary operator, so you'll have to write two lines: `x.addAll(y);return x;`.

Comment: ArrayList is just another mutable object and so is StringBuilder, the other mutable object used as an example in docs. But defining an interface's method so that it serves better with few implementations of mutable objects? Anyway, this is the most convincing of reason's I could get so far. Thanks

Comment: @boobalangnanasekaran Although there are "few" mutable types, they are used very commonly. I think this is a good reason. Also, kindly consider accepting an answer, please.

Answer (score 1):

The `combiner` only used in parallel stream to merge 2 results computed in threads.

Actually, stream use `Consumer` to accumulate results comes from threads. the `result` is saved in `Consumer`, and finally combine partial result from another `Consumer`.

For the `BinaryOperator` combiner is more like the code as below:

```
T[] partials = the result is computed in threads...
T result = supplier.get();
for (T partial : partials)
     result = combiner.apply(result, partial)
return result;
```

For the `BiConsumer` combiner is more like as the code below:

```
T[] partials = the result is computed in threads...
T result = supplier.get();
for (T partial : partials)
     combiner.accept(result, partial)
return result;
```

From stream package [description](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction) :

> As with reduce(), a benefit of expressing `collect` in this abstract way is that it is directly amenable to parallelization: we can accumulate partial results in parallel and then combine them, so long as the accumulation and combining functions satisfy the **appropriate requirements**. For example, to collect the String representations of the elements in a stream into an ArrayList, we could write the obvious sequential for-each form:

```
 ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
 for (T element : stream) {
     strings.add(element.toString());
 }
```

Or we could use a parallelizable collect form:

```
 ArrayList<String> strings = stream.collect(() -> new ArrayList<>(),
                                            (c, e) -> c.add(e.toString()),
                                            (c1, c2) -> c1.addAll(c2));
//  the requirements showing as an example           ---^
```

Comment: For the BiConsumer combiner case in your example,

There is no documented restriction on which argument of combiner, the first or the second should be mutated. Do we have to just assume that `combiner.accept(result, partial)` mutates the first argument? If so why is it not documented, so that implementors of stream API can be assured of such assumption