# Stream.collect(supplier, accumulator, combiner) vs. Collector.of(supplier, accumulator, combiner)

Tags: java, stream, collectors

This is about the difference of the third argument of

```
Collector.of(Supplier<R>, BiConsumer<R, T>, BinaryOperator<R>, Characteristics...)
```

and

```
Stream<T>.collect(Supplier<R>, BiConsumer<R, ? super T>, BiConsumer<R, R>).
```

Is there a "built in" `Collector<? super T, R, R> c` such that
`Stream.collect(c)` will have the same effect as
`Stream.collect(supplier, accumulator, combiner)`?

If I have to "build" such a collector by myself will

```
c = Collector.of(supplier, accumulator,
                 (r1, r2) -> {combiner.accept(r1, r2); return r1;});
```

be correct?
(From the javadoc of the Stream.collect method: "The combiner function must fold the elements from the second result container into the first result container.")

And just for my understanding:
The following would suffice, too, but would be slightly less efficient?

```
c = Collector.of(supplier, accumulator,
                 (r1, r2) -> {R r = supplier.get(); combiner.accept(r, r1); combiner.accept(r, r2); return r;});
```

Comment: From the Javadoc of `#collect(Collector)`: "_Performs a mutable reduction operation on the elements of this stream using a Collector. A Collector encapsulates the functions used as arguments to collect(Supplier, BiConsumer, BiConsumer), allowing for reuse of collection strategies and composition of collect operations such as multiple-level grouping or partitioning._".

Comment: For why the third parameter type is different, see [Why is the combiner of the Collector interface not consistent with the overloaded collect method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30309127/why-is-the-combiner-of-the-collector-interface-not-consistent-with-the-overloade).

Comment: In short: yes to both, `(r1, r2) -> {combiner.accept(r1, r2); return r1;}` is correct and `(r1, r2) -> {R r = supplier.get(); combiner.accept(r, r1); combiner.accept(r, r2); return r;}` would be semantically correct too, but less efficient.